# "unable to parse" IPTC Date to XMP DateTime in exiv2

Tags: c++, parsing, xmp, iptc, exiv2

I am hacking a bit on exiv2, trying to extend it's date/time conversion functions between EXIF, IPTC, and XMP. http://dev.exiv2.org/issues/864

IPTC Date and IPTC Time are stored in separate fields, so first I try to parse IPTC Date, later in my code I try to parse the Time.

I am a rank beginner at programming, so this will look like a pretty basic problem, but here goes. The code is being added to the exiv2 file convert.cpp inside the cnvIptcValue function.

The exact error I get from the command line:

```
$ exiv2 -eiX iptc.jpg 
Warning: Failed to convert Iptc.Application2.DateCreated to Xmp.photoshop.DateCreated, unable to parse '1944-09-08'
Warning: Failed to convert Iptc.Application2.DigitizationDate to Xmp.xmp.CreateDate, unable to parse '2015-03-06'
```

At first I thought that the Date conversion code was failing:

```
if (std::string(from) == "Iptc.Application2.DateCreated" || std::string(from) == "Iptc.Application2.DigitizationDate")  {

int year, month, day, hour, min, sec, tzHour, tzMinute;
char tzSign;
char buf[30];


    if (sscanf(value.c_str(), "%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day) != 3) {

    EXV_WARNING << "Failed to convert " << from << " to " << to
                << ", unable to parse '" << value << "'\n";
    return;
}
```

But further testing showed that it was the Time conversion code that fails:

```
    const char* iptcTime = 0;  
if (std::string(from) == "Iptc.Application2.DateCreated") {
    iptcTime = "Iptc.Application2.TimeCreated";
}
else if (std::string(from) == "Iptc.Application2.DigitizationDate") {
    iptcTime = "Iptc.Application2.DigitizationTime";
}
if (iptcTime) {              
    if (sscanf(value.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d%1c%d:%02d", &hour, &min, &sec, &tzSign, &tzHour, &tzMinute) != 6) {

        EXV_WARNING << "Failed to convert " << from << " to " << to
                    << ", unable to parse '" << value << "'\n";

        return;
    }
```

So the Time code was trying to parse the Date field. This was changed to the Time field by adding a couple of lines of code:

```
    Exiv2::IptcData::iterator iptctime_pos = iptcData_->findKey(IptcKey(from));
    std::string value = iptctime_pos->toString();
```

I also expanded the error message code to see what was in the Time field. the result is now:

```
Warning: Failed to convert Iptc.Application2.TimeCreated to Xmp.photoshop.DateCreated, unable to parse '11:11:14+00:00'
Year Month Day:          1944 9 8
Hour Minute Second:      32767 36913992 1978972555
Zone Sign Hour Minute:   "U+007F"  -184143665 6457088
Warning: Failed to convert Iptc.Application2.DigitizationTime to Xmp.xmp.CreateDate, unable to parse '16:26:47+00:00'
Year Month Day:          2015 3 6
Hour Minute Second:      32767 36909480 36909144
Zone Sign Hour Minute:   "U+007F"  -184143665 6457088
```

It is correctly parsing the Date field, but not the Time. Why is this? Is it parsing the wrong thing?

Comment: I check from http://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/repository/entry/trunk/src/convert.cpp, I found it is using colon `:` rather than dash `-`: `if (sscanf(value.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d", &year, &month, &day) != 3)`. But your code using `-`. Which one is correct?

Comment: EXIF uses a colon, IPTC uses a dash.

Comment: Are you sure the warning is triggered inside `Converter::cnvIptcValue()` , and not inside `Converter::cnvExifDate()` ?

Comment: Okay, I tested that and yes, it is coming from Converter::cnvIptcValue(). But from the later section that tries to parse the Time. I'll modify the question. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the proper way to do this is to create new method `cnvIptcDate()` based on `cnvExifDate()`, and then modify `const Converter::Conversion Converter::conversion_[]` so that `"Iptc.Application2.DateCreated"` now uses `cnvIptcDate()` rather than `cnvIptcValue()`. May be you also need to include `Iptc.Application2.DigitizationDate`, `Iptc.Application2.TimeCreated`, `Iptc.Application2.DigitizationTime` in this array, which also to use `cnvIptcDate()`.

Comment: Agreed, and that is the long-term plan. But first I want to get the basic conversions working, then I will move them into their own methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75022/discussion-between-asp-and-tivn).

Answer (score 0):

Solved! There were two changes needed.

First was to make sure to scan the same key as was set earlier. My trial and error attempts had me scanning from "iptctime" rather then "value", which gave the parse error.

```
std::string value = iptctime_pos->toString();

if (sscanf(value.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d%1c%d:%d", &hour, &min, &sec, &tzSign, &tzHour, &tzMinute) != 6) {
```

Second was to add an `else if` preventing the DateTime properties from being re-written by the general assignment code.

Full working result is:

```
if (std::string(from) == "Iptc.Application2.DateCreated" || std::string(from) == "Iptc.Application2.DigitizationDate")  {

    int year, month, day, hour, min, sec, tzHour, tzMinute;
    char tzSign;
    std::string iptctime;
    char buf[30];


    (sscanf(value.c_str(), "%d-%d-%d", &year, &month, &day)

    const char* iptcTime = 0;  
    if (std::string(from) == "Iptc.Application2.DateCreated") {
        iptcTime = "Iptc.Application2.TimeCreated";
    }
    else if (std::string(from) == "Iptc.Application2.DigitizationDate") {
        iptcTime = "Iptc.Application2.DigitizationTime";
    }
    if (iptcTime) {              
        Exiv2::IptcData::iterator iptctime_pos = iptcData_->findKey(IptcKey(iptcTime));
        if (iptctime_pos == iptcData_->end()) return;
            if (iptctime_pos->key() == iptcTime) {
                std::string value = iptctime_pos->toString();

                sscanf(value.c_str(), "%d:%d:%d%1c%d:%d", &hour, &min, &sec, &tzSign, &tzHour, &tzMinute)
        }
    }
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%04d-%02d-%02dT%02d:%02d:%02d%1c%02d:%02d",
         year, month, day, hour, min, sec, tzSign, tzHour, tzMinute);
    buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = 0;
    (*xmpData_)[to] = buf;
}

else if (std::string(from) != "Iptc.Application2.DateCreated" || std::string(from) != "Iptc.Application2.DigitizationDate")  {

        (*xmpData_)[to] = value;
}
```

A bit more testing and I will upload this to the exiv2 repo, to be featured in the upcoming exiv2 0.25 release!

PS: Thank you @tivn for your help.